# How to write subdocuments for an already created document with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've created this Schema:

```
const lolDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref:'User'},
    id: {type: String},
    name: {type: String},
    accountId: {type: String},
    puuid: {type: String, unique:true},
    lolServer: {type: String},
    summonerLevel: {type:Number},
})

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, require: true, unique:true},
    email: {type: String, require: true, lowercase: true, unique:true},
    password: {type:String, require: true, select: false},
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    LolData: lolDataSchema
});
```

The user was already created, I just need to fill the info from the "lolDataSchema". For that, I've tried with this function, but when I look at the db, the data wasn't saved. What i'm doing wrong?

```
module.exports = {
    async saveSummoner(req, res) {
        const lolDataApi = await axios.get(`https://${server}.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/${req.body.name}?api_key=${api_key}`).catch(error => console.log(error));
        User.findOneAndUpdate(req.body._id, { $push: {LolData: lolDataApi.data} } );
        console.log(lolDataApi.data);
        return res.json(lolDataApi.data);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findOneAndUpdate doesn't not return the new updated document instead it returns the original by defaults  if you are using mongodb use `{new:true}` if you are using mongoose use instead `{returnOriginal:false}`
try and us this

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(req.body._id, { $push: {LolData: lolDataApi.data}},{returnOriginal:false}, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error while updating");
        }
        console.log(doc);
    });
```

Comment: still returns error on console:
error while updating
undefined

what does this undefined referes to?

Comment: message: 'Tried to set nested object field `LolData` to array `[object Object]` and strict mode is set to throw.',
  name: 'ObjectExpectedError',
  path: 'LolData'

Comment: your LolData is nested what does it look like in your schema

Comment: Turns out it worked when i put brackets in the UserSchema at { lolData: [lolDataSchema] }. Because of that data is now in an array. Is it possible to do without it?Thx for your help!